# Setting two different yRanges in one graph with two plots

Tags: iphone, graph, range, core-plot

I'm using coreplot in my app. I'm plotting two plots at the same time, each one with it's own data. I'd like to have plot1 to correspondent with the left y-Axis and plot2 with the right y-Axis.

So when the data in plot one has got values from 0 to 45 I'd like to have a yRange from 0 to 50 and plot2 has got values from 0 to 1. I like to have the yRange of the right y-Axis from 0 to 1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add a second plot space to the graph. Assign the first plot and the left axis to the first plot space and the second plot and right axis to the second plot space.